# On click scroll not working on fixed divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to `scrollTop` my left side div but due to some reason, it is not working.

So the following is my CSS, HTML and jquery code. I had tried many things but was failed. Now if you please help me to solve this, then it will be great.

```js
$('#leftside').click(function(e) {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 600);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: .79em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Frutiger, Calibri, 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  height: auto;
}

#content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 39px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#leftside {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: #364150;
  position: relative;
}

#rightside {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  top: 39px;
  right: 0;
  left: 239px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.right-content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  ..... head code
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    nav..... code
  </nav>

  <div id="content-wrapper">

    <div id="leftside">
      <ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="rightside">
      <div class="right-content">
        Right side content
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Would you please help me why the above is not working or what wrong I am doing.

Comment: What is your expected bahaviour?

Comment: I made a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPgQNy, this seems to be behaving as expected. Check for JS errors and make sure the click event is firing.

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery, but forget to add your code within document ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ... //your codes come here
    });
</script>
```

And if you don't like jQuery use this as Event Handler:

```
document.getElementById("yourid").addEventListener("click", function( event ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to scroll the main body/html in your code, change "html, body" to "#leftside".

```
$('#leftside').click(function(e){
  $("#leftside").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
});
```

You should also set the overflow of the left div to 'scroll':

```
#leftside {
      width: 240px;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-top: 5px;
      background-color: #364150;
      position: relative;

      overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Cheers!!